# Eclipse DS-5 Add Button

Tags: eclipse, arm, ds-5

I use the command window in my Elcipse DS-5 for ARM Cortex-M3 setting and clearing of named registers and bits which I have defined separately.

I usually have to type something like this in the command window for bits to get modified:

```
set var $Peripherals::$CFG::$ConMdl.TX1DFELDX = 1
```

I then click on submit and this bit gets set.

I would like to add a simple menu or a few buttons that would allow me to simply click a button and have these commands executed.

Does anybody know how to do this?

E

[image]